# How to unzip .tar.gz file blob storage either using power bi or Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory

I need to unzip .tar.gz files generated in an azure blob storage container using power bi. I can able to unzip .zip files using power bi but it is not working for .tar.gz extensions. Can anyone help me on this?

Also is there any way to to unzip it using ADF? If ADF can help, I can use that as medium then use it in my Power BI files.

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory can zip/unzip in flight using Copy Activity and Binary data sets.

To Unzip, you need to specify the Compression type in the source DataSet configuration:
[image]

In the Copy activity Source, you can specify whether or not to retain the zip file name as a folder:
[image]

NOTE: when using Binary data set for the Source, you also have to use a Binary data set for the Sink.